# Lua Remove all Characters up to and Including 2nd ":" In start of String

Tags: lua

I need to remove all characters up to and including the second colon.

```
ABC: Test B:Keep All: This
```

results:

```
Keep All: This
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `str` is your string, you can simply `match` the relevant part: `str:match"^.-:.-:(.+)"`

Explanation: `^` forces the pattern to start right at the beginning of the string. Then it ignores as few characters as possible until it reaches the first semicolon, same for the next. After that, everything is in the capture group, and all remaining characters will be captured.